# AngularJS component data binding not works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I built my first component using AngularJS 1.7.8 but two-way data binding not works.
I can initialize my component using "<" but not "=".

Javascript component

```
angular.module("App").component("timeComponent", {
    template: "<div class=\"form-group\"><label class=\"control-label col-xs-3\">{{$ctrl.label}}</label><div class=\"col-sm-9\" style=\"display:inline-flex\">" +
        "<select ng-change=\"$ctrl.change()\" ng-model=\"$ctrl.hour\" class=\"form-control\" style=\"width:65px;\">" +
        "<option ng-repeat=\"o in $ctrl.hours\" ng-value=\"o.value\">{{o.label}}</options>" +
        "</select>" +
        "<select ng-change=\"$ctrl.change()\" ng-model=\"$ctrl.minute\" class=\"form-control\" style=\"width:65px;\">" +
        "<option ng-repeat=\"o in $ctrl.minutes\" ng-value=\"o.value\">{{o.label}}</options>" +
        "</select>" +
        "</div></div>",
    bindings: {
        label: "@",
        value: "=",
        min: "<",
        max: "<"
    },
    controller: function () {
        var vm = this;

        vm.hour = 0;
        vm.minute = 0;
        vm.hours = [{ value: 0, label: "0" }, { value: 1, label: "1" }, { value: 2, label: "2" }, { value: 3, label: "3" }, { value: 4, label: "4" }, { value: 5, label: "5" }, { value: 6, label: "6" }, { value: 7, label: "7" }, { value: 8, label: "8" }];
        vm.minutes = [{ value: 0, label: "0" }, { value: 25, label: "15" }, { value: 50, label: "30" }, { value: 75, label: "45" }];

        vm.$onInit = function () {
            vm.min = vm.min || -1;
            vm.max = vm.max || -1;
            console.log("init", vm.value);
            vm.value = vm.value || 0;
            vm.hour = Math.trunc(vm.value);
            vm.minute = Math.trunc(((vm.value - vm.hour) * 100));
            console.log("$onInit", vm);
        }

        vm.change = function () {
            vm.value = vm.hour + (vm.minute / 100);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<time-component value="Object.workHours" label="Hours" max="8.25"></time-component>
```

The parameter "Object.workHours" is loaded using $http.get.

If i use "$ctrl.value" in template the value is displayed, but if i use "vm.value" in controller the value is undefined.

**UPDATE**

I reproduced the problem in this [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/SI8AvLuIfNVlNCiI34dg?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

I have just found the solution to my problem

```
$scope.$watch(() => this.value,
   (newValue, oldValue) => {
      vm.hour = Math.trunc(this.value);
      vm.minute = Math.trunc(((this.value - this.hour) * 100));
});
```

Here the new [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ByMSCeNzDv9B30DXRDy3?p=preview) with the solution.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. It works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UN4xL2CvjPWQcsMwXe2M?p=preview).

Comment: Please see [this PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/SI8AvLuIfNVlNCiI34dg?p=preview)

Comment: Isn't the default name for Controller binding $ctrl, and if you want to change it you need to specify that it's `controllerAs: vm`?